# Flutter AppBar Long Title not Centered

Tags: flutter, dart

When using a long a title in an AppBar it becomes not centered, even with center title enabled.

Any suggestions to fix this issue?

[image: Example Image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you use centerTitle: true property in App Bar? How are you setting your App bar?

Comment: Yes I have centerTitle: True. I think it is because the title is too long, but maybe there is a work around.

Answer (score 0):

If the title is dynamic, adjust the font size based on the length of the string. Otherwise, specify the font size directly.

```
AppBar(
  title: const Text(
    'Here is the long title',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
  ),
  centerTitle: true,
);
```

you can also use something like [responsive_sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_sizer) or [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) to adjust your font size based on the device.